# Solve full page opacity issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, avgrund

I have a webpage where the opacity does not cover the entire page. I tried using z-index to solve this issue but for some reason it is not working.

Here is the webpage: http://www.fairdash.com/test-page

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4gqs4275/light/

Here are my CSS trials:

Replacing `.avgrund-cover` with `.avgrund-active` to no success.

I've added `.avgrund-active {visibility: visible; opacity: .55;}` and removed `opacity:1;` from `.avgrund-active .avgrund-cover`.

Note: I can only edit the code located in the JSFiddle to solve this issue.

Comment: The jsFiddle works fine here.

Comment: The problem is on my website.

Comment: The element `.avgrund-cover` is inside the `.webs-bin` that has a `position:relative` property and prevents the `.avgrund-cover` from growing.

Comment: Complementing what @Peruggia said, you have some other elements positioned and with z-index defined. They're not being covered up with your _mask layer_. It's not about opacity. It's about the coverage of your layer.

Comment: @Peruggia is there a way I can use the CSS to override the `.webs-bin`?

Comment: @user2680614 Yes. The `.webs-bin` class is in a file called `sitebase.css`, to override it you can "include" your css file after that one and then write, for example, .webs-bin { position: static; }. And you must consider what @MelanciaUK said about the `z-index`.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, Please hear me out, I do not know what JSFiddle is, but I HAVE come up with a possible solution. You see, what you need to do is make a , background black, and then set the opacity to 0.4, and the z-index to above the page but below the popup, then, simply make a function in JQuery, or another framework/library, and then fade it in. I have prepared some example code below:

```
    $("#opacityDiv").fadeOut(0);

    $("#whateverthebuttoniscalled").click(function(){

    $("#opacityDiv").fadeIn(400);


    });

    $("#opacityDiv").click(function(){

    $("#opacityDiv").fadeOut(400);

    });
```

Glad I can help.
You have a cool effect there!